# New rails application without Controller and Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How to start a new rails project with only ActiveRecord module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails doesn't create any controllers or views by default. `rails new <project>` will give you a new Rails project with no controllers or views.

If you want to explicitly exclude ActionController, comment out the relevant railtie:

```
# config/application.rb.

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
# require "action_controller/railtie" # comment this line
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Comment: Yes. I want to skip ActionController and ActionViews files, Like -O skips Activerecord. I want to keep activerecord instead and skip other modules

Comment: You can't. If you want to just use ActiveRecord, then you're not building a **Rails** application. You should start a new project and add the ActiveRecord gem.

Comment: The I don't get all other magic and importantly `rails console`, sexy rake commands, I think it is more work otherwise, Instead if I just skip Controller and Views I get lot more. Correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: Then make a new project, and don't add any views or controllers. You cannot *remove* ActionView or ActionController, they are part of ActionPack which cannot be removed from Rails. More importantly, there's *nothing to skip*. As I said, Rails doesn't make any controllers or views for you.

Comment: Hmm.. what would you do? Include ActiveRecord in non rails project and write code for the required magic to happen or start rails project and not write view? Now I am confused here. Also, I am working on this new idea and don't want to put lot of time in things that I can get readymade with little bit of overhead.

Comment: No, I would make a new Rails app, and not create any controllers or views, **just like I'm telling you to do**. What part of this aren't you getting? You cannot skip generation of files that aren't generated. Adding a `-O` flag to "skip" ActionController or ActionView would have **no effect**.